# How do I prevent pointer from jumping when tapping touchpad?

Tags: arch-linux, xterm, touchpad, i3

I'm running i3 with xterm in Arch Linux on a laptop. My issue is that whenever I try to move the mouse cursor, it seems to initially register it as a tap, causing the cursor to teleport to the spot on the screen corresponding to where on the touchpad I started moving from. This is an issue since it essentially makes the top edge of the screen unclickable.

How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common cause of touchpad issues on Arch Linux, including the one you are describing, is not installing the Synaptics touchpad driver.  The package is called `xf86-input-synaptics`

Go ahead and run `pacman -Syu xf86-input-synaptics` and then restart X, and your touchpad should start behaving normally.